# How to set Mac server to use different Gateway for internet bound traffic

Tags: networking, mac-osx, ip, routing, switch

Here is a network diagram of what we have so far:

http://www.philosophydesign.com/downloads/officenetwork.png

We have recently added a second internet connection that gives better outbound speed for use of offsite backup for our fileserver (Mac Server). I have setup the modem/router to have dhcp off and its network to 192.168.2.* and plugged it into our office switch. At the moment its not effecting any of the existing network. To be able to use the new internet connection a computer on the network needs to manually asign its IP in the 192.168.2 range.

What I want setup is that the Mac fileserver makes any office based connections on the current network but any connections on the Mac server that is destined for the internet uses the new internet connection and not the existing one like it is doing now. The Mac server only has one network port thats plugged into the switch.

I'm assuming I need to assign another IP on the Mac server on the new network and setup some routing on the server but this is where I get stuck. Can anyone offer some help on how I go about setting the config up?

Thanks

Scott

Comment: +1  for including your network graphic! I don't mean to be pedantic, but especially when discussing networking, Mac is not spelled in all caps (when referring to the Apple Macintosh). MAC refers, of course, to Media Access Controller, the caps signaling an acronym. "IP on the MAC" just looks strange to me.

Comment: @msanford - Noted about the Mac thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the second modem an address on the 192.168.1.0/24 network.  You don't need a separate network for this.

On your Mac server, set the "default route" to the address of the second modem.  With this configuration, your server will continue to talk to other systems on the network exactly as it does now, but for any off-network traffic it will use the second modem while other systems use the first modem.

Comment: Just going to test this. BRB